# DELETE and PUT endpoints don't work after implementing Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, spring-security

I'm currently developing a fullstack web application with a React Frontend and Spring Boot backend. I've implemented Spring security and JWT for authentication, but I can't access my API endpoints (see Controller) ever since. I've managed to access the GET request endpoints, but none of the PUT or DELETE requests seem to work despite logging in on the backend before starting a request.

I've seen that disabling csrf solved the problem in another post, but I've never enabled it anyway, so that wouldn't do the trick for me.

WebSecurityConfig file:

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/v*/registration/**")
                    .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and()
                .formLogin();
    }
```

Controller (REST API)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/question")
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class QuestionController {

    private final QuestionService questionService;

    @Autowired
    public QuestionController(QuestionService questionService) {
        this.questionService = questionService;
    }

    @CrossOrigin("*")
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Question>> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Question> questions = questionService.findAllQuestions();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(questions, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @CrossOrigin("*")
    @GetMapping("/find/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Question> getQuestionById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        Question question = questionService.findQuestionById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(question, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @CrossOrigin("*")
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<Question> addQuestion(@RequestBody Question question) {
        Question newQuestion = questionService.addQuestion(question);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newQuestion, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @CrossOrigin("*")
    @PutMapping("/update/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Question> updateQuestion(@RequestBody Question question) {
        Question updateQuestion = questionService.updateQuestion(question);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(updateQuestion, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @CrossOrigin("*")
    @DeleteMapping("(/delete/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Question> deleteQuestion(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        questionService.deleteQuestion(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Example for the GET request endpoint that works:
[image]

Example for the DELETE request endpoint that doesn't work:
[image]

Edit: This is the Code for implementing UserDetailsService

```
@Service
@Autowired can be left out by using this annotation.
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BenutzerkontoService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final static String USER_NOT_FOUND_MSG = "User with email %s not found";

    private final BenutzerkontoRepository benutzerkontoRepository;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    private final ConfirmationTokenService confirmationTokenService;

    public List<Benutzerkonto> findAllBenutzerkonto() {
        // findAll() returns a list of all user objects
        return benutzerkontoRepository.findAll();
    }

    /**
     * This method is responsible for identifying the given email inside the database.
     *
     * @param email
     * @return
     * @throws UsernameNotFoundException
     */
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return benutzerkontoRepository.findByEmail(email).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format(USER_NOT_FOUND_MSG, email)));
    }

    /**
     * The following function checks, whether the user already exists (by email) and registers the user with an
     * encoded password, if the email address does not exist already.
     *
     * The user also gets a random JSON Web Token assigned
     *
     * @param benutzerkonto
     * @return
     */
    public String signUpUser(Benutzerkonto benutzerkonto) {
        // Check whether user exists
        boolean userExists = benutzerkontoRepository.findByEmail(benutzerkonto.getEmail()).isPresent();

        if (userExists) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Email is already taken");
        }

        // Encode the user password
        String encodedPassword = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(benutzerkonto.getPassword());

        // Replace the plain text password with the encoded version
        benutzerkonto.setPasswort(encodedPassword);

        // Save user to database
        benutzerkontoRepository.save(benutzerkonto);

        // Create random String via the UUID class for using it as token
        String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        // Instantiate ConfirmationToken class, which defines the token for account confirmation
        ConfirmationToken confirmationToken = new ConfirmationToken(
                token,
                LocalDateTime.now(),
                // Make token invalid after 15 minutes
                LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(15),
                benutzerkonto
        );

        // Save token to database
        // TODO: Shouldn't it be saved by a confirmationTokenRepository object? Why does this also work?
        confirmationTokenService.saveConfirmationToken(confirmationToken);

        return token;
    }

    /**
     * This function takes the email address as a parameter and enables/activates the email for logging in.
     *
     * @param email
     * @return
     */
    public int enableAppUser(String email) {
        return benutzerkontoRepository.enableAppUser(email);
    }

    /**
     * This method adds a new user account to the database, but it searches for the passed value of email
     * inside the database first. The user object "benutzerkonto" will only be saved in the database repository,
     * if the email does not exist already.
     *
     * @param benutzerkonto
    */
    public void addNewUser(Benutzerkonto benutzerkonto) {
        // userEmailPresence can be null, if the email does not exist in the database yet, which is why it's an Optional.
        Optional<Benutzerkonto> userEmailPresence = benutzerkontoRepository.findBenutzerkontoByEmail(benutzerkonto.getUsername());
        if (userEmailPresence.isPresent()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Email already taken.");
        } else {
            benutzerkontoRepository.save(benutzerkonto);
        }

    }

}
```

Edit2: This is the user class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table

public class Benutzerkonto implements Serializable, UserDetails {

    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "student_sequence",
            sequenceName = "student_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "student_sequence"
    )
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String passwort;
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserRole rolle;
    private Boolean locked = false;
    // false by default, because user has to confirm via email first
    private  Boolean enabled = false;

    // Constructor
    public Benutzerkonto(String email, String passwort, UserRole rolle) {
        this.email = email;
        this.passwort = passwort;
        this.rolle = rolle;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Benutzerkonto{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", passwort='" + passwort + '\'' +
                ", rolle=" + rolle +
                ", locked=" + locked +
                ", enabled=" + enabled +
                '}';
    }

    // Methods of UserDetails interface
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(rolle.name());
        return Collections.singletonList(authority);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return passwort;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return !locked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: *but none of the PUT or DELETE requests seem to work despite logging in on the backend before starting a request.* Sure you have to authenticate first, that's what you implemented with `anyRequest().authenticated()`.

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint in method `deleteQuestion`? Your response is 404, that means you controller method is not found or the method could't found the object.

Comment: Exactly, I've logged in on the backend via the Spring Security login form and then accessed the delete endpoint. I haven't figured out, why it can't be found yet though

Answer (score 1):

So apart from requests coming to `/api/v*/registration/**` others are secured. What does that mean?, it means until you have authorized users having authorized roles cannot access any other endpoint. So you need to do some things like:

1. implement `UserDetails` of package `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails` and implement the method:

   ```java
   @Override
   public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
     return roles == null?null:roles.stream().map(m->new SimpleGrantedAuthority(m.getAuthority())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
   ```
2. Add roles to your entity class:

   ```java
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
   @JoinTable(
        name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "user_id",
                referencedColumnName = "id"
        ),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "role_id",
                referencedColumnName = "id"
        ))
   private List<Role> roles;
   ```
3. Use those roles in your endpoint:

   ```java
   @PreAuthorize(hasRole('ROLE_role_name'))
   @GetMapping(path = EndPoint.PATIENT_HOME, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
   public ResponseEntity<YourDTO> Home(Principal principal) {

       return new ResponseEntity<YourDTO>(yourDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
   }
   ```

Comment: @lu_lu have you added the @PreAuthorize(hasRole('ROLE_role_name')) to your endpoint that failing?

Comment: You should just paste in the code in the stackoverflow text field, mark it with your mouse and then click the { } button from the stackoverflow text editor, it automatically applies syntax highlighting

Comment: Your first step would unfortunately interfer with my user class (benutzerkonto) implementation, regarding the getAuthorities method. So I couldn't use your solution yet, but I've edited my post, maybe you can take a look at it

Comment: @lu_lu add single role to list of roles and remove the constructor argument of the role

Comment: @lu_lu did this work? if so you can accept the answer

Comment: unfortunately it did not work, but the deadline is in a few hours so I won't work myself into Spring Security furthermore. Thanks anyway for your help!